# Removing null entries from a ArrayList

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, google-maps-android-api-2

I am retrieving the addresses form `GeoCoder` *GoogleMapApi* and before passing the result ahead of to a `Spinner` object I need to remove all the null entries from the list.

I tried following two ways but none of them are making any difference:

```
locs.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
locs.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

-

```
private List<Address> getAddress(double latitude, double longitude,int maxResults) {
    Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        locs = gCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, maxResults);
        locs.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
        //locs.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return locs;

}
```

Comment: I think second way should certainly work. Did you try it with a separate list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    List locs = new ArrayList();
    locs.add("");
    locs.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
    System.out.println(locs.size());
```

output

```
0
```

and this

```
    locs.add("");
    locs.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
    System.out.println(locs.size());
```

output

```
1
```

there is a difference

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through list with this code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < locs.size(); i ++){
        if (locs.get(i) == null){
            locs.remove(i);
            i --;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)`
{
`if(list.get(i)==null||list.get(i).equals(""))// in case of string only otherwise only one`check is sufficient
`{`
       list.remove(i);
`i--;`
   }
`}